# How to delete a specific line in a text file (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Using any windows commands, how can you accomplish this?

e.g. delete line 2 in file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done in a BAT script.

Read `HELP FOR` and `HELP SET` and then try this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (t.txt) do (
 set /a count=count+1
 if /i !count! NEQ 2 echo %%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe that can't be done in with the command line, it is kind of a complex requirement.

would you like to explain in more detail your task?

here is a code snippet in c# that can help you.

```
        string filePath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        string line;
        string NewText = string.Empty;

        if (File.Exists( filePath ))
        {
            StreamReader file = null;

            int linecounter = 0;

            file = new StreamReader( filePath );
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(linecounter==1)
                {
                     linecounter ++;
                     continue;
                }


                linecounter ++;
            }
           //then save the new text in a file or overwrite your current file
```